# Centered content with header from left to center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I didn't know what would be the best title for my question...

Well, I'll show what I want to do with a simple picture:

[image]

The issue:

- I have my content centered, lets say it's 980px width.
- Now, my header will have a logo and a menu.
- BUT, I want my header to
  use only a left side of the top, like 50% of the content width and
  then stretch to the left side of the viewport. I know this is
  possible using javascript and calculate the left offset of the
  content and set the dynamic width div with it's left offset.

Is it the best way? I believe there should be another way, but I can't think of one. Hope you guys have a better idea than mine, since mine slows down the perfomance of the site when I resize the window.

Comment: I would think a negative left margin should work on the inner div.

Comment: @Mike please explain your comment better

Comment: Can you rephrase what you want? It's not very clear...

Comment: check out twitter bootstraps fluid layouts, it could solve this problem

Comment: @Four_lo and then how do I get the center of the content?

Comment: @AlfredXing I'm after the labeled "Dynamic Width" one that will expand or contract, depending on the browser width (please keep in mind that: that div has no content, only background-color).

Comment: do you know the height of the header? if its fixed height then ill try to make a sample

Comment: @silentw Yeah, I get it now. I thought your "content" was the browser window at first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have 2 `div`s; one in the background and one to contain the logo?

http://jsfiddle.net/kUKyp/1/

Comment: @trajce It's the only pure-CSS way I can think of. The hardest part with this is that the content is fixed width... Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is margin:auto in CSS. It's very simple:

1. Put your content div on the page, with a fixed width of say 980px as you wanted and set margin:auto.
2. Put your logo and menu div inside content.

Here is a good example of this in action:

http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

The CSS code from the above page:

```
body {
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px; /* Need to set body margin and padding to get consistency between browsers. */
    text-align:center; /* Hack for IE5/Win */
    }

#Content {
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto; /* Right and left margin widths set to "auto" */
    text-align:left; /* Counteract to IE5/Win Hack */
    padding:15px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
```

And the markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="Content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm after, I'm after the labeled "Dynamic Width" one that will expand or contract, depending on the browser width (please keep in mind that: that div has no content, only background-color).

Comment: So you want to put something into the dynamic width div is what you're saying?

Comment: Basically, it's like the header is coming from the left side of the monitor but it only has the logo and the menu "inside" the content div.

Comment: Is it just a background you need to propagate across the full width of the page or do you need to put markup into it? It's a key clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using twitter bootstraps fluid layouts

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12">
             <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="span6">   (6 for half of the width, number can be changed 1-12)                        your logo and menu
                  </div>
            your content
             </div>
         </div>
```